# How to input a character array at run time, with spaces being read

Tags: java

I want to enter characters in a character array, dynamically, at run time, using java. But I am not able to find any scanner function for it. If i give input as a string and then extract characters from it, then also the spaces are not being read.

```
Scanner sm=new Scanner(System.in); 
String sl=sm.next();
int i; 
char ch[]=new char[sl.length()]; 

ch=sl.toCharArray(); 

for(i=0;i<sl.length();i++) 
{ 
     System.out.print(ch[i]); 
}//This gives output Hello for input Hello world
```

Comment: Can you provide the code you wrote so far.

Comment: "_If i give input as a string [...] spaces are not being read._" `str.toCharArray();` will include spaces. Have you tried that?

Comment: Scanner sm=new Scanner(System.in);
  String sl=sm.next();
  
  char ch[]=new char[sl.length()];
  ch=sl.toCharArray();
     
  for(i=0;i<sl.length();i++)
  {
   System.out.print(ch[i]);
   
  }  //This gives output Hello for input Hello world

Comment: Edit your code into your original post.

Comment: I have made the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
        char[] line = reader.readLine().toCharArray();
        for (char c : line)
            System.out.print(c);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
```

May I ask what drove you to use Scanner? It's almost never the right answer.

Comment: Hey thankyou very much good friend!I am completely new to java programming.I will keep it in mind and use the buffered class now.

Comment: @Dmitri can you explain why it's not the right answer to use Scanner? I use it quite often when dealing with user input in java programs, just because it's easy to use. I see no disadvantage at all.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.nextLine()` instead of `.next()`, and it should include spaces. The default delimiter for Scanner is whitespace, so if you use `.nextLine()` instead, it will use the \n for a delimiter, and it will take all the input up until you pressed enter.

```
Scanner sm = new Scanner(System.in);
String sl = sm.nextLine();
int i;
char ch[] = new char[sl.length()];

ch = sl.toCharArray();

for (i = 0; i < sl.length(); i++) {
    System.out.print(ch[i]);
}//This gives output Hello world for input Hello world
```